# Can't get Matrox quad head working

Tags: 13.04, graphics, xorg

I have xubuntu 13.04 newly installed. I'm trying to get my Matrox M9148 gpu to work. I had to create and edit an xorg.conf file, and now the card outputs to all monitors, but no program windows display, even though they are there and I can interact with them. It's like their alpha is set to 0. Even the login screen window is gone, only the background image is present, and the desktop icons if I login. Also, the mouse will travel to the other monitor, but changes to an X, and the cursor is duplicated on screen 0 as an X.

I'm on my phone, or I'd attach xorg.conf file. I'll do that when I can.

===================================================

Here's xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen3"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" Below "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor3"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Independent"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "UseKernelModule"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon0_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon1_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon2_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon3_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ICDOP1"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ICDOP2"                # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      0
        Option      "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "kmsdev"                # <str>
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      1
        Option      "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      2
        Option      "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card3"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      3
        Option      "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen3"
    Device     "Card3"
    Monitor    "Monitor3"
EndSection
```

Comment: Hi - you appear to have two accounts - please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it working, but not like I wanted. I use xrandr in ~/.xprofile to setup the screens when I login, which is fine, but I don't understand why it won't work in xorg.conf.

Here's my .xprofile:

```
xrandr --output mon0 --pos 528x0
xrandr --output mon1 --right-of mon0
xrandr --output mon2 --below mon1
xrandr --output mon3 --left-of mon2
```

And here's what I ended up with in xorg.conf:

```
    Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
#   Option "RightOf" "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
#   Option  "Below" "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor3"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
#   Option "Below" Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Independent"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "UseKernelModule"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon0_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon1_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon2_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon3_forcedvi"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ICDOP1"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ICDOP2"                # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
#   Option      "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "kmsdev"                # <str>
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
#   Driver      "modesetting"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
#   Option "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card2"
#   Driver      "fbdev"
    Driver "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
#   Option "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card3"
    Driver      "m9x"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
#   Option      "Independent"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes   "1680x1050" "1600x1200" "1400x900" "1280x800" "1280x768" "1152x864" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes   "1680x1050" "1600x1200" "1400x900" "1280x800" "1280x768" "1152x864" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes   "1680x1050" "1600x1200" "1400x900" "1280x800" "1280x768" "1152x864" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen3"
    Device     "Card3"
    Monitor    "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
        Modes   "1680x1050" "1600x1200" "1400x900" "1280x800" "1280x768" "1152x864" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "QuadScreen"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 528 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1681 0
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 1681 865
    Screen      3  "Screen3" 0 865
    Option      "Xinerama"   "true"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

I wish I could get X to work by itself without needing the xrandr stuff, but on the login screen, it looks like all all of the screens are there but just stacked up on top of each other and are mirrored/duplicated on all of the monitors.

No big deal right now because it's working, but if anyone has any clues, I'd love to hear them....

Answer (score 1):

This is my xorg.conf that worked on 10.04 with the Matrox M9140.  I tried it with 13.04, and it works.  I'm using gdm (not lightgdm).  My monitors are physically arranged like this:

```
[2][3]
[1][4]
```

and heres my /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
        FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "record"
        Load  "dri"
        Load  "extmod"
        Load  "dbe"
        Load  "glx"
        Load  "dri2"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
        Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "monitor1"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "monitor2"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        Option          "Above" "monitor1"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "monitor3"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        Option          "RightOf" "monitor2"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "monitor4"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
        Option          "Below" "monitor3"
EndSection


Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Independent"               # [<bool>]
        Option     "UseKernelModule" "On"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon0_forcedvi"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon1_forcedvi"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon2_forcedvi"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "mon3_forcedvi"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ICDOP1"                    # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ICDOP2"                    # [<bool>]
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "m9x"
        VendorName  "Matrox Graphics, Inc."
        BoardName   "M91XX"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        Option          "monitor-mon0" "monitor1"
        Option          "monitor-mon1" "monitor2"
        Option          "monitor-mon2" "monitor3"
        Option          "monitor-mon3" "monitor4"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
Section "Extensions"
  Option "Composite" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: All your cards are `PCI:1:0:0` are you sure you need four device sections. I even wonder whether you need xorg.conf at all these days, xorg is autodetecting most possibly all of this.